# Exclude observations that do not exist for all quarters from data source in SAS Visual Analytics

Tags: sas-visual-analytics

I want to create a filter that will exclude observations that don't have a value for all 3 quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3 of 2016) in my dataset. Here's an example of my dataset:

Identifier | Quarter | Value
ABC3456    | 2016Q1  | 145
ABC3456    | 2016Q2  | 159
XYZ874     | 2016Q3  | 226
ABC3456    | 2016Q3  | 311

The outcome, after the application of the filter should be:

Identifier | Quarter | Value
ABC3456    | 2016Q1  | 145
ABC3456    | 2016Q2  | 159
ABC3456    | 2016Q3  | 311

because XYZ874 does not have values for Q1 and Q2 of 2016.

I have experience with Advanced filters but only to include or exclude values based on one variable. Searching through this site and the internet I can't find a solution.

Please provide an answer for SAS Visual Analytics and not SAS Enterprise Guide.

Thanks in advance.